# custom query counting and grouping dates

Tags: mysql

From a database, I'm trying to find profiles that have been updated in the last X days and group them based on date.

My SQL structure looks like this:
id (int)
date_modified (date)

which produces a result something like this:

```
+----+---------------+  
| id | date_modified |  
+----+---------------+  
| 86 | 2012-06-22    |  
| 87 | 2012-06-22    |  
| 88 | 2012-06-22    |  
| 89 | 2012-06-22    |  
| 63 | 2011-10-31    |
| 72 | 2012-02-06    |
| 60 | 2011-10-17    |
| 71 | 2012-02-29    |
| 69 | 2011-11-18    |
| 76 | 2012-02-29    |
| 70 | 2011-11-18    |
| 75 | 2012-02-29    |
| 73 | 2012-02-06    |
| 74 | 2012-02-28    |
| 77 | 2012-02-29    |
| 80 | 2012-05-07    |
| 82 | 2012-06-12    |
| 83 | 2012-08-15    |
| 84 | 2012-09-07    |
| 85 | 2012-08-15    |
+----+---------------+
```

Ideally, I would want to work the query so it produces a result like this:

```
+-------+----------+  
| total | days_ago |  
+-------+----------+  
| 4     | 1        |
| 6     | 2        |
| 8     | 3        |  
| 12    | 7        |
| 3     | 30       |
| 55    | 90       |  
| 28    | 180      |  
| 37    | 270      |  
| 42    | 360      |  
+----+-------------+
```

Where it's converting the date_modified to a number of days ago and grouping it in the increments shown above.

I'm assuming this would be possible using cases in the select query, but I'm a bit at a loss for how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) MySQL function:

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

In your case, it's simply solved by using

```
SELECT COUNT(date_modified) as total, DATEDIFF(date_modified, NOW()) as days_ago FROM mytable GROUP BY date_modified;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need in table name - tbl, insert your query which you use now. For specific date you need now() change to '2012-06-10'.

Query **[SQLFIDDLE example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a46f1/6)**:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(id) total ,
DATEDIFF(now(),date_modified) days_ago 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY date_modified
ORDER BY days_ago
```

Result:

```
| TOTAL | DAYS_AGO |
--------------------
|     1 |       54 |
|     2 |       77 |
|     4 |      131 |
|     1 |      141 |
|     1 |      177 |
|     4 |      245 |
|     1 |      246 |
|     2 |      268 |
|     2 |      348 |
|     1 |      366 |
|     1 |      380 |
```